# How to set eslint to ignore @import from scss files

Tags: reactjs, sass, eslint

In React project, I am running linter on js and scss files. In scss files, I have used @import statement but lint gives me following error

```
Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'import'
@import './../shared/variables.scss';
```

I want linter to ignore these @import lines.

Do I need to add any rule in in eslintrc file?
Currently I am having following import rules in config:

```
'import/no-unresolved': 0,
'import/no-dynamic-require': 0,
'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 0
```

Is there any comment line for scss files to ignore specific line, like we have it for js files? e.g. `// eslint-disable-next-line`

I have gone through a lot of online sources and added babel-eslint parser as well and also passed parserOptions too but nothing is working.

Comment: Looks like the cause is eslint 'src/**' command. You are linting other files than JavaScript/typescript.
eslint is not for linting styles.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12752#issuecomment-571561845 :

> Looks like the cause is eslint 'src/**' command. You are linting other files than JavaScript.

Comment: try this, "npx eslint --ext .jsx --ext .js lib/". Here is reference : https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface#pass-multiple-values-to-an-option